# Is the Android Emulator browser suitable and reliable for testing an HTML/Javascript Application?

Tags: javascript, html, android, testing, emulation

I'm developing an HTML / Javascript application meant to run on an Android device running Froyo (2.2). Assuming I don't need multitouch functionality, will the emulator's browser be a reliable means of debugging HTML, CSS and Javascript? Or is it possible that I would work out all the bugs in the emulator but find the actual device handles things differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying code for WebKit is identical in the emulator and the actual device. The only thing you need to worry about are the other components inbetween (some carriers have proxies, for example. I used to have problems with T-Mobile where it would simply send me a outdated cached version of a site instead of even contacting the site).